# draw outline border on Text component

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to draw a border over a `Text` in SWT...
This is what I got for now:

public class BorderedText extends Text {

```
public BorderedText(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
            if (isFocusControl()) {
                Color color = new Color(getDisplay(), new RGB(82, 168, 236));
                e.gc.setAlpha(200);
                e.gc.setForeground(color);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0, getClientArea().width-1, getClientArea().height-1);

                Transform t = new Transform(getDisplay());
                e.gc.setTransform(t);

                e.gc.drawRoundRectangle(0, 0, rect.width,  rect.height, 4,4);
            } else {
                e.gc.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0, getClientArea().width-1, getClientArea().height-1);

                e.gc.drawRectangle(rect);
            }
        }
    });
```

When the component receive focus, he is like this
[image]

But when I type something, he got screwed up
[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I gave up on `Text` and done it with `StyledText`

public class BorderedText extends StyledText {

```
public BorderedText(Composite parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.WRAP);

    setTabStops(new int[] {0});
    addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
            if(isFocusControl()){
                e.gc.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION));
                e.gc.drawRoundRectangle(0, 0, getClientArea().width-1, getClientArea().height-1, 6,6);
            } else {
                e.gc.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                e.gc.drawRoundRectangle(0, 0, getClientArea().width-1, getClientArea().height-1, 6,6);
            }
        }
    });

    addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            redraw();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            redraw();
        }
    });

    addControlListener(new ControlListener() {

        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            redraw();
        }

        @Override
        public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
            redraw();
        }
    });

addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.character == SWT.TAB){
                e.doit = false;
                traverse(SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void checkSubclass() {
    //
}

@Override
protected void checkWidget() {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. You can create a new Text widget with SWT.BORDER as a style argument. This would give you a nice looking border.
2. You can use the StyledText widget. The StyledText widget enables you to define margins.

Comment: when I use SWT.BORDER I can't draw my own border and i don't want to use StyledText

Comment: Well is there any reason not to use StyledText?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your Text widget in a Composite? You can draw your border on the Composite.