# How to Set the color of org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text borders

Tags: java, textbox, swt

I have a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text box.

```
private org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text textBox = new Text(parent , SWT.BORDER)
```

how do i set the border color for this text box? Setting background can be done using setBackground, but i did not find any option for border!

I found this:
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/168-eclipse/1570-how-to-add-colored-border-around-the-text-widgets.html
Now how do i notify the paintListener?
Basically upon a condition border should change to red!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522774/draw-outline-border-on-text-component

Answer (score 0):

You just call **redraw()** when you what to toggle between clean and red. The paint listener will be called automatically.