# Set StyledText BorderColor with StyleRange

Tags: java, swt

I´m trying to set the BorderColor of a [StyledText](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyledText.html) widget. 
The [StyleRange](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyleRange.html) Object allows me to set the fields borderColor and borderStyle.

My code looks like this:

```
StyledText test = new StyledText(parent, SWT.BORDER);

Display display = Display.getCurrent();

Color color = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);

StyleRange style = new StyleRange();
style.borderColor = color;
style.borderStyle = SWT.BORDER_SOLID;

test.setStyleRange(style);
```

But this code does not set the Color of the Border. I know there is a workaround by using a paint listener but why does the above example doesn´t work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified a start position and length for the style range so it isn't actually styling anything.

Just to be clear `StyleRange` sets a border around some text in the `StyledText` it does not set the border of the control.

As an example, here is a `StyledText` with several `StyleRanges` specifying a border:
[image: Style Ranges]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I thought a StyleRange can be used for the whole Control as well. Then I stick to the Paint Listener method as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522774/draw-outline-border-on-text-component).